# send email with body having css style in android or ios

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova

I am developing app using phonegap for android and ios. I want to send an email from the app. I add inline styles, i can append text in email body but i see it as simple text without any formatting.
How to achieve this? I want to use ,  tags.
**Evan i want to show image in email body (not as attachment)

Please help

Comment: Hi Sushant. Did you have any update on this? I have the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @JoãoMenighin, use Emailcomposer plugin for both of them. In iOS it works great but in android it has very limited scope in css styling. Check answer to this question. Follow each step and install the same plugin through terminal in iOS.

Comment: Im actually using it already. As I am only testing on android I thought the CSS was not working at all. Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: yeah right. on android it supports only `italic`, `bold`, `underline`. If you get any other option, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try installing the email composer plugin. It works fine - https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

or 
https://github.com/GalCohen/EmailComposer-phonegap-plugin

I would like to refer GiGi's Answer here: [Phonegap : capture Image, Video and Send as Attachment in Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949827/phonegap-capture-image-video-and-send-as-attachment-in-email)

Comment: hi @rajmathan, thanx for reply, I am using emailComposer only, but its not opening 'new maail' of my iphone 4's email app. And have tried same on android, it works fine, i can send email except css issue

Comment: Almost all phonegap developers facing like this css alignment issues between ios and android devices. One solution is we should use css properties which is opt for the platform.