# Creating advanced HTML e-mails in Android app

Tags: java, android, html-email

I am fairly new to coding. I'm kind of experimenting with Android apps. I tried to build a HTML e-mail to send a prospect with loan information. 
This is what I used:

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "random subject");
    shareIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            Spanned stuffinHtml);
```

The problem is that when the e-mail client is launched it shows plain text and ignores the formatting. Is this the correct way or am I missing something?

Regards!

Comment: Have you tried 
`shareIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            Html.fromHtml(stuffinHtml));` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but gmail release support to html in his email body.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

check here. according to this gmail doesn't support css in Head and Body tag in html.

**and here is some solutions, i know its not relevant but may be prior solution for anyone.**

Please try installing the email composer plugin. It works fine - [Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949827/phonegap-capture-image-video-and-send-as-attachment-in-email)

I would like to refer GiGi's Answer here: [Phonegap : capture Image, Video and Send as Attachment in Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949827/phonegap-capture-image-video-and-send-as-attachment-in-email)